# Redmine meeting booking plugin returns 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: http, docker, redmine

I have installed the Redmine on ubuntu using docker. And I installed this plugin for booking meeting rooms (https://github.com/dro123/redmine_meeting_room_calendar).

But after finish the installation, when I submit the booking form to book a meeting room, there is an error "Unprocessable Entity". The server returns "422 Unprocessable Entity" without any other information. I have tried many methods but they doesn't work. Could anybody help me figure out what's the problem is?

Thanks

Following is my request:

Request URL: http://XXXXXX:3000/meeting_room_calendar/create?key=5a273b023b6d2377c4014468ed19d41555be0161&project_id=3&author_id=1&assigned_to_id=1&category_id=0&subject=Redmine+Admin&start_date=2018-06-09&due_date=2018-06-09&custom_field_values%5B1%5D=Room+1111&custom_field_values%5B2%5D=09%3A00&custom_field_values%5B3%5D=09%3A15&event_id=0&recur=false&periodtype=1&period=5

Request Method: GET

Status Code: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Comment: You also need to specify the version of Redmine, that you are using. Possibly, that's because the plugin does not support your version of Redmine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my Redmine version is as follows:
Environment:
  Redmine version                3.4.4.stable
  Ruby version                   2.3.5-p376 (2017-09-14) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  Rails version                  4.2.8
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               PostgreSQL
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.8.8
  Darcs                          2.8.4
  Mercurial                      2.8.2
  Cvs                            1.12.13
  Bazaar                         2.7.0
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_meeting_room_calendar  3.0.0

Comment: 3.4.4 is the recent version, the plugin was updated years ago. So, I believe, it just does not support 3.4. I think, it needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I should try some other plugins or Redmine whose versions are matched with each other. Thank you again.